# JS - JSON.parse - preserve special characters

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parsing, non-ascii-characters

I'm running a NodeJS app that gets certain posts from an API.
When trying to `JSON.parse` with special characters in, the `JSON.parse` would fail.

Special characters can be just any other language, emojis etc.

Parsing works fine when posts don't have special characters.
I need to preserve all of the text, I can't just ignore those characters since I need to handle every possible language.

I'm getting the following error:

```
"Unexpected token �"
```

Example of a text i'm supposed to be able to handle:

```
"summary": "★リプライは殆ど見てません★ Tokyo-based E-J translator. ここは流れてくるニュースの自分用記録でRT＆メモと他人の言葉の引用、ブログのフィード。ここで意見を述べることはしません。「交流」もしません。関心領域は匦"�アイルランドと英国（他は専門外）※Togetterコメ欄と陰謀論が嫌いです。"
```

How can I properly parse such a text?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have misdiagnosed your problem, it has nothing to do with that character.

Your code contains an unescaped `"` immediately before the special character you think is causing the problem. The early `"` is prematurely terminating the string.

If you insert a backslash to escape the `"`, your string can be parsed as JSON just fine:

```js
    x = '{"summary": "★リプライは殆ど見てません★ Tokyo-based E-J translator. ここは流れてくるニュースの自分用記録でRT＆メモと他人の言葉の引用、ブログのフィード。ここで意見を述べることはしません。「交流」もしません。関心領域は匦\\"�アイルランドと英国（他は専門外）※Togetterコメ欄と陰謀論が嫌いです。"}';

    console.log(JSON.parse(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a string not as an object.

Example

`JSON.parse('{"summary" : "a"}');`

In your case it should be like this

`JSON.parse(
'{"summary" : "★リプライは殆ど見てません★ Tokyo-based E-J translator. ここは流れてくるニュースの自分用記録でRT＆メモと他人の言葉の引用、ブログのフィード。ここで意見を述べることはしません。「交流」もしません。関心領域は匦�アイルランドと英国（他は専門外）※Togetterコメ欄と陰謀論が嫌いです。"}')`

Comment: I just gave part of the json string thats causing me the problem. That string is part of a larger properly formatted json. thanks